# case return nothing for specific condition

Tags: elixir

Having this code:

```
defmodule TestQuery do

  def build_query() do
    Enum.map(["test1", "test2", "hello"], fn item ->
      query(item)
    end)
  end

  def query(item) do
    case String.contains? item, "test" do
      true -> item
      false -> nil
    end
  end

end
```

If I run it I will end with this list:

```
iex(2)> TestQuery.build_query()
["test1", "test2", nil]
```

How can you avoid adding `nil`? or do nothing on `false` clause?

This example is a simple example of a method which makes queries and that query might return a `nil` (404), I want to build a list with the successful queries, without the `nil` items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three ways I can think of:

1. Use `Enum.filter/2` and return `true`/`false` from `query`:

   ```
   def build_query() do
     Enum.filter(["test1", "test2", "hello"], fn item ->
       query(item)
     end)
   end

   def query(item) do
     String.contains? item, "test"
   end
   ```

   This won't work if your actual `query` function wants to return a value that's not `item`.
2. Remove all `nil` values at the end:

   ```
   Enum.map(["test1", "test2", "hello"], fn item ->
     query(item)
   end) |> Enum.reject(&is_nil/1)
   ```

   This won't work if `item` is `nil` because it'll be removed as well.
3. Use `Enum.flat_map` and return an empty list instead of `nil` and a non-empty list in case of not nil:

   ```
   def build_query() do
     Enum.flat_map(["test1", "test2", "hello"], fn item ->
       query(item)
     end)
   end

   def query(item) do
     case String.contains? item, "test" do
       true -> [item]
       false -> []
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`Enum.filter/2` returns only those elements for which the second arg returns a truthy value. In Elixir everything is truthy except nil and false. So, you can just use your query function in this way (no need to add anonymous function):

```
Enum.filter(["test1", "test2", "hello"], &query/1)
```

Or for that particular example:

```
Enum.filter(["test1", "test2", "hello"], &String.contains?(&1, "test"))
```

Or you even can use comprehensions and map successful queries into another list:

```
for item <- ["test1", "test2", "hello"], String.contains?(item, "test"),
  do: on_successful(item)
```